# SQL SERVER: Checking if a number belongs to a comma separated group of integers

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following table

```
id | value              | 
-------------------------
1  | 1,2-5,6,9-1500,1505|
2  | 1,2,3,6,9          |
```

I want to create a select query to retrieve all the rows where the number X belongs to the set in the value column.

For example

```
SELECT id WHERE 3 BELONGS TO value

Output:
1
2
```

Or

```
SELECT id WHERE 1499 BELONGS TO value

Output:
1
```

Is there a way to create this type of query without using any C#?

Comment: Never, ever store data like that. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: @jarlh In this case I can´t save it in rows since I can have a range of values like 1-100000. This would take a lot of space if I had to store each number in a different row.

Comment: Space is cheap, processing data like that is not.

Comment: For example you can store start value and end value, different columns in the same row.

Comment: You would need a stored procedure in the SQL Server database.

Comment: @jarlh that is a very good suggestion. I did not think about that. Could you write that as a reply to my question and I will mark it as the soluction? Thanks.

Comment: Think about what happens when you want to take value '1000' out of your 9-1500 group.    Somehow you have to find out that 1000 is part of 9-1500, remove that substring, and insert 9-999 as well as 1001-1500.  Yikes.

Comment: @DanielOliveira please note that you will still need multiple rows with the same `id`, so if `id` is your primary key you may need to create another table that has `[id, fkId, startValue, endValue]` and you would have multiple rows to describe each range.

Comment: If you normalize your data to have a `start_value` column and an `end_value` column, then you can just do `select distinct id from the_table where some_value between start_value and end_value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments to the question, you can avoid a lot of messy string parsing (e.g., in a Stored Procedure or a Scalar-valued Function) by storing the value ranges in rows of a table like this:

```
1> SELECT * FROM ValueRanges;
2> go
id          StartValue  EndValue
----------- ----------- -----------
          1           1           6
          1           9        1500
          1        1505        1505
          2           1           3
          2           6           6
          2           9           9

(6 rows affected)
```

Then you can simply query for matching [id] values like this

```
1> SELECT id FROM ValueRanges WHERE 3 BETWEEN StartValue AND EndValue;
2> go
id
-----------
          1
          2

(2 rows affected)
1> SELECT id FROM ValueRanges WHERE 1499 BETWEEN StartValue AND EndValue;
2> go
id
-----------
          1

(1 rows affected)
```